Typescript imported any class from Huawei packages @react-native-agconnect is undefined
I have React Native with Typescript project on Expo. I'm trying to use Huawei services (agconnect package), particularly I want to add applinking to redirect users from different platforms to my in-app content.
So for that reason I'd:

installed @react-native-agconnect/applinking v. ^1.3.0

imported it into my App.tsx file and saw an error message:


Could not find a declaration file for module '@react-native-agconnect/applinking'. 'c:/path/node_modules/@react-native-agconnect/applinking/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try 'npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-agconnect__applinking' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module '@react-native-agconnect/applinking';'ts(7016)


installed npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-agconnect__applinking, but it gave me error:

npm error code E404
npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-native-agconnect__applinking - Not found
npm error 404
npm error 404  '@types/react-native-agconnect__applinking@*' is not in this registry.
npm error 404
npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.


added declare module "@react-native-agconnect/applinking"; to env.d.ts file and import @react-native-agconnect/applinking error disappeared

added:


const androidLinkInfo = {
            "packageName": "com.huawei.agc.rn.applinking.example",
            "androidDeepLink": "https://huawei.com/",
            "openType": AgcAppLinking.AppLinkingAndroidLinkInfoAndroidOpenTypeConstants.APP_GALLERY
        }

and got error:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot set property 'ShortAppLinkingLengthConstants' of null, js engine: hermes

So it looks like pure Typescript error, when it can't see js-modules. Here where I stacked (
PS I'd also had tried to delete and reinstall all the packages but with no luck.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but did you take a look at the examples available on github https://github.com/AppGalleryConnect/agc-demos ?

See full re-production of the error above in the edited description
